# How can I receive -3 from an answer?

Tags: support

"Achievements" shows -3 for the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996951/how-to-set-java-classpath-in-bash-script-used-in-ubuntu-and-windows-cygwin/39997032#39997032).

How can that work? I don't see how [the reputation system](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) could give me a -3 on an *answer* that I have given?! Actually I am wondering how I could get -3 on anything?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you hit the rep cap on that answer, yesterday:

[image]

You lost 10 from the un-upvote, and 15 from the un-accept. (25 total)
Then you got 7 rep from the upvote, and 15 from the accept. (22 total)

However, at the time you were upvoted again, you were only 7 rep away from the rep cap, meaning the remaining 3 rep weren't awarded.

Comment: Stupid question: how do you get to that view?

Comment: In your [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1531124/ghostcat?tab=reputation), there's the reputation tab, where you can group your rep by post.

Comment: Shrug. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: So, this answers your question, then?

Comment: Yep. Just forgot about it ... and when I first saw your answer, it was too early to accept.